# URGENT need of help for Accordion using JSON to add into to make it collapsible?

Tags: accordion

I need urgently to create the accordion in SPO page, and am using JSON to input into the Format View side.  I have a list with 3 columns - Category, Question and Answer

I need it create the accordion for the FAQ based on these three columns.

I am not a coding person and I need someone to help with the coding for the following

I can only created till here.  how to make the following?

1. Header (Category) to show on top of the Question?
   Answer - click to read -collapsible
2. how to make the code with the accordion?

Here's my code.  Please help.

how to insert code here to show??

Answer (score 0):

To display the category, use the following code. As to making it clickable and expand, this is not possible using list formatting alone.

Your best bet there would be a SPFx web part, you can check out the one at [sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-faqapp) for inspiration.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "align-items": "flex-start"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-borderColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white"
        },
        "style": {
          "font-size": "24px",
          "border-width": "2px",
          "border-style": "solid",
          "width": "100%",
          "padding": "4px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Category]",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontColor-themeTertiary"
            },
            "style": {
              "font-size": "10px",
              "padding-right": "10px",
              "font-weight": "bold"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$Question]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-borderColor-themeDark"
        },
        "style": {
          "padding-left": "40px",
          "width": "100%",
          "border-width": "2px",
          "border-style": "solid",
          "padding": "4px",
          "font-size": "14px",
          "border-top-width": "0",
          "margin-bottom": "20px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$Answer]"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, I checked the link.. not sure which file to use,  testing but don't get the image that was provide in it.. can help?

Comment: You must follow the instructions under the section **Minimal Path to Awesome**. If you haven't set up your environment for SPFx development you should follow the instructions here: [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) first.

Comment: ok will try it out. tks